# Warning - incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *__strong' with an expression of type 'UITextField'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I got this code and XCode warns me of "incompatible pointer types initializing NSString *__strong with an expression of type UITextField".

```
NSString *name = (UITextField *)searchText.text;
```

but this one is fine

```
NSString *name2 = [(UITextField *)searchText text];
```

and this one is fine too

```
NSString *name3 = [(UITextField *)searchText.text mutableCopy];
```

I have two questions:

1. I am confused with `obj.*` and `[obj *]`
2. Why is the "mutableCopy" correct is this case?

I don't know how to search in Apple developer documentation for these questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version, due to operator precedence, you're casting `searchText.text` to a `UITextField*`, what you want to do is probably to cast `searchText`;

```
NSString *name = ((UITextField *)searchText).text;
```

In the second version you don't have the dot, so the compiler understands your cast to be casting searchText to `UITextField` and send the text message to it. In other words, exactly right.

The last case is a bit tricky since it involves both runtime and compile time. As I understand it;

- You cast `searchText.text` to a `UITextField*`. The runtime still knows that the object is an NSString and the `mutableCopy` message that exists on both will go to the correct method [NSString mutableCopy] anyway and create/return a mutable copy of the NSString so runtime it works out ok.
- Since `mutableCopy` returns `id` (referencing a NSMutableString), the assignment to an NSString is ok by the compiler (id can be assigned to anything), so compile time it's ok.

A question, what is `searchText` originally? That the last version compiled without warning indicates that it's already an `UITextField*`, or at least a type that can take the `text` message. If so, you should be able to just do;

```
NSString *name3 = [searchText.text mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second and third examples, the cast just operates on searchText.  So with these you are sending a message to a UITextField object.

In the first one, the cast applies to the whole of searchText.text.  Assigning a UITextField object to a NSString variables is not what you want.  The code you're looking for is:

```
NSString *name = ((UITextField *)searchText).text;
```

The mutableCopy message returns a copy of your string as a NSMutableString object, which can be assigned to a NSString as NSMutableString derives from it.  In this case using the 'copy' message is just as good.

Hope that helps.